# How to hide preference screen behind a second one?

Tags: android, screen, preference

I have two `PreferenceScreen` . 
I use the theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings`.
So when I load the second layout, the first layout can be seen under the second layout.

I want to hide the first preference screen, not remove it.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an onClick or other method that sends you to the second preference screen, in this method you could call:

```
 setContentView(.R.drawable.black_image);
```

to change the view of the activity in the background

also don't forget to reset it when in your onResume();